# How do I access MySql database in C#.NET with WPF?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ado.net

Please advise me. I am trying to develop Windows Application in WPF with Mysql server database.

Which approach I have to use to create connection establish on the Mysql database?

1) Entity Framework
OR
2) ADO.NET
OR
3) Other one

The Admin computer need to install mysql database on his computer and then access the mysql database to another (10 or more) client systems which are under network connected.

Here, just one MySql database inside admin computer only. And all other client machines are accessing MySql database by admin's computer IP address. The IP connection string is like this:-

```
 @"Data Source=10.0.0.101
```

One of other matter is, the customer demanding that, when installing .exe file on client machine, then should have to automatically install mysql server database (ie, xampp or other ect..) also.

How can I do this?

I have tried, ADO.NET C# instead EF to connect mysql for wpf windows application. like that :-

```
public void AddUserList( UserSetUp user)  
    {  

        dbConnection.Open();  
        string query = "INSERT INTO Tble_UserSetUp (FirstName, SurName, Email, PhoneNumber, UserName, Password,Computer_Name,IP_Address,CreatedBy, CreatedDate,IsActive,Function,Department) VALUES (@FirstName, @SurName, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @UserName, @Password,@Computer_Name,@IP_Address,@CreatedBy, @CreatedDate,@IsActive,@Function,@Department)";  
        MySqlCommand insertSQL = new MySqlCommand(query, (MySqlConnection)dbConnection);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FirstName);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", user.SurName);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", user.PhoneNumber);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Encrypt(user.UserName));  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Encrypt(user.Password));  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Computer_Name", user.Computer_Name);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP_Address", user.IP_Address);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", user.CreatedBy);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", user.CreatedDate);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", user.IsActive);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Function", user.Function);  
        insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", user.Department);  
        try  
        {  
            insertSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            dbConnection.Close();  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);  
        }  
    }
```

Is it a bad idea instead of use Entity Framework or another one?

Comment: you can install MySQL by setting prerequisites refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/32bdcbcb-e9d2-40cd-8a5a-ec3530db2b32/create-an-installer-for-c-with-mysql?forum=winformssetup  for information on the same.

Comment: EF *uses* ADO.NET. WPF has nothing to do with data access. Neither is broken. Instead of trying random things, decide whether you need an ORM first. PS. there are a *LOT* of duplicate questions about MySQL and ADO.NET

Comment: BTW what is the *actual* question? As it is, this text could be summarized in "How do I access databases in .NET?"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Do you mean the ADO.NET writting such code is the only way for insert and get data from mysql to wpf application? If it is I am planning to follow such ADO.NET code style for the windows application. Is it good thought?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I have changed my question tag. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please focus on one question. This question is too broad, ranging from choosing a data layer (too broad in itself) to how to install a database.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    /*mysql
     * 
     * 1. add nuget mysql.data.dll（desktop application）
     * 2. using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
     * 3. code like bellow , you can try 
     */
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mysql();
        tbx.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
    private void mysql()
    {
        try
        {
            var connstr = "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=123456;database=world";
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from city where countryCode= @ID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "100");
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var ii = reader.FieldCount;
                            for (int i = 0; i < ii; i++)
                            {
                                if (reader[i] is DBNull)
                                    sb.AppendLine("null");
                                else
                                    sb.AppendLine(reader[i].ToString());
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I will follow as you say. One of other matter is, the customer demanding that, when installing .exe file on client machine, then should have to automatically install mysql server database (ie, xampp or other ect..) also.

How can I do this?

Comment: @johnsonANDjohnson Do you mean that , you install mysql server on your client machine? Usually we install mysql server in a server machine, and apply the server IP to the `connstr`.

Comment: No Sir, I mean install mysql on server machine. But the customer want to install mysql on server mechine automatically when installing .exe windows application for server mechine (there is two window apps one is for client mechine and another one is for server mechine) . How can I do that? or I am thinking, without using mysql instead by use sqllite.s3db. Is it good way? Please reply advice me sir

Comment: @johnsonANDjohnson Sqlite is only design for local use, it not support access from other computer over net. As far as i can see, you must install mysql in your client's server and config mysql server.

Comment: sir admin system and client systems both are network connected. So, can I use sqllite.s3db? becuase customer demanding me, they want a .exe file on admin system but mysql server (xampp or another one) should install automatically both are at the same time. How can I do that ? Please help me.

Comment: As for sqlite ,  you can read this [Is it possible to use SQLite as a client-server database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-it-possible-to-use-sqlite-as-a-client-server-database). 'server (xampp or another one) should install automatically', sorry , i have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

Reference: Official MySQL documentation - [Introduction to Connector/NET Programming](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html)

Step 0: Setup MySql and [Create a database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-use.html)

Step 1: Create WPF Project

Step 2: Install MySql.Data package using Nuget package manager

> (Visual Studio) Project> (click) Manage NuGet packages

Select Browse tab> search `Mysql.data` > Select `Mysql.data` package> Install

Step 3: In my case I created the connection within `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file.

To consume MySql.Data and MySql.Data.MySqlClient

```
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Full Code (relevent to the question): `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace EAppartments
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=YourDBName;password=yourpassword";
        
        //Connect to MySql when app starts
        //you can use OnStartUp event as well
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectToMySql();
        }


        private void connectToMySql()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            //close connection if you want
            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Useful resources:

[Execute MySql commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) using WPF app

[Lifecycle of WPF application](https://codecompiled.com/lifecycle-wpf-application)

Comment: How does this answer the question? You pick one little phrase out of it ("create connection"). The question is too broad to answer anyway, ranging from which data layer to how to install a database. Also, when answering *is* possible, [please don't post screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your advice. I'm new to C# WPF development and MySql (2-3 weeks experience).